# In a typical clinical longitudinal trial, why do marginal models (MMRM, GEE) are much more common than conditional ones (mixed)?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, generalized-estimating-equations

I read statistical analysis plans and reports of over 80 longitudinal trials. I noticed, that in 70% they were analysed using a marginal model, namely the MMRM approach (mixed-model repeated measures). MMRM has weird name, as there is nothing "mixed", pure fixed-only regression with residual covariance specified, fit with GLS or GEE estimation, depending on the distributional assumptions holding or not.

I was told, that this is a popular approach, because here we are interested here in a global effect of the treatment A vs. B, population-average, averaging over the clusters, patients, random effects. This is why always, with non-identity links, the beta coefficients, the marginal effects of a model are smaller than in mixed models. They are "attenuated". This is a consequence of ignoring patient-specific results and looking "globally". I was told that this also reflects the need, by regulators, to prove the treatment working globally and *not* in any sub-groups. Ideally assuming zero interactions. In other words, it's said: "I don't care about any specific effects, I want to know whether there is a difference or not".

The others told me, that this is wrong. Typically a researcher would say: "I want to know, what is the difference, if I applied treatment A or B to an individual". Those coefficients are always (assuming non-identity link) larger.

For a researcher, which approach is more important?

- marginal model, ignoring cluster-specifics (this sensitive to Simpson's paradox), giving smaller magnitude of effects, conservative, giving "overall" answer about the whole population and NOT a single patient. OK, it's more robust to miss-specification of the covariance (but not mean's structure!), distributional issues, but is this of ANY usefulness?
- conditional model, which takes it all into consideration, which focuses on the specific patient and not some "virtual population". OK, it's more complex to fit, requires unverifiable assumptions and is sensitive to miss-specification of both mean's structure and covariance, but gives me the answer expressed in patient terms!

I'm totally confused and currently nobody could tell me which one may be more important in this case.

I don't know. I'm not a statistician. I know some terms, as you can see, but that's too few!
And statisticians ask me always the same question: do you want a marginal or patient-specific model?

I have no idea which one should I choose.

Is comparing treatments over time better in terms of the whole population and not patients? But the effects will always be smaller.

Is comparing treatments over time better in terms of thinking about a specific patient and not populations? These effects will always be larger, so better for me, right? Or not? Maybe they are falsely exaggerated?

What's your opinion?

Let's assume that statistical software can fit both.

EDIT: I just thought, that, say, comparing if something works for males and females (by sex) makes no sense with mixed model, as patients will never change the sex on biological level (I mean it won't change their DNA, hormones, enzymes, lab reference ranges). So here we want to compare between GROUPS of males and females.

But regarding treatment? It's possible for a patient to take drug A OR B, to switch.